# Changing views automatically and alternately with Django and Celery

Tags: python, django, django-views, celery

I'm making a django app that is going to change views automatically after 10 seconds in each views when open. There are 2 views only.

I've never used Celery before, That's a test app that I'm gonna change to do a project.

As you can see below, What i'm trying to do is to call the other view after 10 seconds and so on.

But the only thing that is going on is that each view is renderd after exact 10 seconds when I type the url, They aren't changing alternately

Any help is appreciated

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
import time


@shared_task
def open_view(request):
    current_url = resolve(request.path_info).url_name

    if current_url == 'view1':
        time.sleep(10)
        return redirect("view2")

    if current_url == 'view2':
        time.sleep(10)
        return redirect("view1")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.tasks import open_view


def view1(request):
    open_view(request)
    return render(request, 'view1.html')


def view2(request):
    open_view(request)
    return render(request, 'view2.html')
```

Comment: This isn't a thing you could do with Celery. You need JavaScript for this.

Comment: Pure javascript or some other tool ?, If you can get me some materials to learn to use python along with javascript I'd be immensely grateful.

Comment: So, what are you trying to do in the first place? See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/218374)

Answer (score 0):

You can't push anything from the server to a browser without some cooperation on the browser's end (or, as Daniel said, you need JavaScript).

Here a JS solution that will redirect you once from view1 url to view2 (and the opposite):

```js
var redirect_url = null;

// .endsWith needs to be polyfilled for IE!
if (location.href.endsWith('view1')) {  
    redirect_url = '/view2#'  // Use # at the end to prevent alternation
} else if (location.href.endsWith('view2')) {
    redirect_url = '/view1#'
} else if (location.href.endsWith('#')) {
    location.hash = ''  // remove the #
}

if (redirect_url) {
    // redirect after 10 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {location.href = redirect_url}, 10000);
}
```